# error in visual studio when using visual GDB debugger

Tags: c++

I am building inkscape source code containing cpp files in visual studio. To compile I have used visual gdb(debugger).
by https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Using_Visual_Studio following this link.
But I am facing 3 errors
1.command line action failed in visual gdb.
2.Build has failed.see the output window for more details.
3.MSB3073, makefile target error in makefile

Comment: And did you check the output for more details, as the error tells you to do?

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes.it is showing the path with config-->Release-->"Platform:visual GDB"exited with code 1 in output window.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.